# Statically using namespace

Tags: c++

This may be a duplicate but I didn't see exactly similar question.
Does a `using namespace` declaration stops at the end of it's source file if not written in header ?

`foo.cpp`

```
using namespace foo; // will this using namespace's scope end at the end of this file?
some random code...
```

or do we need to create a scope ?

`bar.cpp`

```
{
    using namespace bar;
    some random code...
}
```

Comment: If it doesn't stop at the end of the `.cpp` file you're compiling, where do you expect it to continue?

Comment: You cannot have a random scope like that, these are only allowed in function scope. [Compiler will not accept that](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kmsRwWNb92zysY5P).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Good question x) I don't know but I just wanted to be sure

Comment: Of course, if you have `#include`d `foo.cpp` into another file (which is generally a bad idea), then the `using` will continue into the parent file, affecting the entire [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that in the 99% of time your `using namespace ...` is limited to the single .cpp it's in and other .cpp files don't have it.

But you should learn about *compilation units* and how they work with the *preprocessor*. Usually a single *compilation unit* is a single source file. That single source file might often have `#include` instructions to the *preprocessor*. If your `using namespace bar;` happens *before* that `#include`, then the namespace will pollute that header.

You won't see that pollution from another .cpp file *unless the namespace causes differences*. So for example, if you have a namespaced function `bar::min`, then `using namespace bar;` right before `#include` will change what `min` functions are available to the header. So in `foo.cpp` it might use `bar::min` but then in `bar.cpp` it might use `std::min`. That might or might not cause errors, warnings, or even differences at runtime. It really depends on what names are affected.